# random timeout for every class object

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using this function to call an effect on objects, which are showing up several times on my page:

```
setTimeout(function () {

    $(".effect-object").each(function(){
        $(this).addClass("effect");
    });

}, Math.random() * 10000);
```

Right now the effects are being fired all at the same "random" time. I want the effect on every class to be played at its own random time.

I tried doing it like this, but it didn't work:

```
    $(".effect-object").each( setTimeout( function(){
        $(this).addClass("effect");
    }, Math.random() * 10000));
```

how can I make this work?

Comment: there is a syntax mistik  :)

Comment: where exactly is the mistake?

Answer (score 1):

You need to put `setTimeout` inside the `each` callback

```
$(".effect-object").each(function(_, el) {

  setTimeout(function() {
    $(el).addClass("effect");
  }, Math.random() * 10000));

})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use it this way :

**PS**: I'm using an `arrow function` here so the context of the `.each()` method going to be used inside of the `setTimeout` function

```js
$('.effect-object').each(function() {
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log($(this).html());
  }, Math.random() * 2000);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- 1 -->
<div class="effect-object">
  1
</div>

<!-- 2 -->
<div class="effect-object">
  2
</div>

<!-- 3 -->
<div class="effect-object">
  3
</div>

<!-- 4 -->
<div class="effect-object">
  4
</div>
```

Comment: I think this would have worked and looking up the syntax for the arrow function brought me this "old" way of doing it as you can see in my reply. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You were almost there, just you have missed `function()` after `.each`

```
$(".effect-object").each(function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        $(this).addClass("effect");
    }, Math.random() * 10000)
});
```

Comment: this does not work, as `this` will not refer to `.effect-object` anymore in this case.

Comment: it does, `$(this)` refers to the instance of `.effect-object` as we are traversing through each DOM of `.effect-object`

Comment: but why doesn't it work for me then? in the mozilla developer documentation it says, that `this` allways calls the object of the function it is locatet in:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

so as I understand, it actually can't work in this situation, as `this` is being blocked by the surrounding function.

Comment: did you try adding `function()` inside `each()`?

Answer (score 0):

I found this solution now, which serves me best. I defined a variable "that" in order to pass "this" to the inner function.

```
$(".effect-object").each(function(){

    var that = this;

    setTimeout(function () {

        $(that).addClass("effect");

    }, Math.random() * 10000); 

});
```

thanks to gregory NEUT for his advice with the arrow-function, this actually gave me this idea and would have been possible as well!